# Creating a more generic makefile

Tags: c, generics, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= ---
LDFLAGS = ---

all: abc_test   
abc_test: abc_test.o defn_abc.o abc.o cmocka_compass.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) abc_test.o defn_abc.o abc.o cmocka_compass.o -o 
abc_test    
abc_test.o : abc_test.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) abc_test.c 
defn_abc.o : ../defn_abc.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ../defn_abc.c
abc.o : ../abc.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ../abc.c    
knownfile.o : ../../../../../knownpath.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ../../../../../knownpath.c
clean: 
    rm *o *.log abc_test
```

Which will work (changed some files names) but I want to make it generic. I tried the following but I keep getting errors that there are no targets.

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= ---
LDFLAGS = ---

SRCFILES := $(shell find ../ -name '*.c')
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,%(SRCFILES))

OBJFILES: all
all: $(OBJFILES)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) %< -o %@

knownfile.o : knownpath.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) knownpath.c
```

the make file is a test folder, which contains all the test code (abs_test.c). This is also where all the objects should go. One directory up contains the c files defn_abc.c and abc.c.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

---

UPDATE: Here is my latest makefile, with the error 'missing separator'

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -DUNIT_TESTING -DSYS_LINUX -Ipath1 -Ipath2
LDFLAGS = -Wl,---


SRCFILES := $(shell find ../ -name '*.c')
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCFILES))

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJFILES) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

all: $(OBJFILES)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) %< -o %@

knownfile.o : knownpath.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) knownfile.c
```

Comment: Arent you overwriting variable  OBJFILES in consecutive lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I would recommend you read about the basics of Makefile. This is a useful link [intro to makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html)*

The variable `OBJFILES` is being over-written in consecutive lines in the example provided. I suspect removing line

`OBJFILES: all`

and using patsubst as

`$(patsubst %suffix,%replacement,$(var))`

might help.

@edit: Since now you asked  on how to use `LDFLAGS` and get rid of the 'missing separator' error, here are some suggestions.

- Purpose of `LDFLAGS` is to use to provide link time flags to compiler when all the object files are linked to make the final executable. They could look like this

> ```
> all: $(PROG)
>
> $(PROG): $(OBJFILES)
>     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJFILES) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
> ```

- The error '*missing seperator*' is fixed by inserting tabs instead of space in the beginning of a line describing an action/recipe to a rule. Open the Makefile again in an editor and remove the spaces in front of below lines and replace with tab.. the arrow I am using to show a tab

> ```
> ---->$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJFILES) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
>
> ---->$(CC) $(CFLAGS) %< -o %@
>
> ---->$(CC) $(CFLAGS) knownfile.c
> ```

Comment: I still get this error:

make: *** No rule to make target `%(SRCFILES)', needed by `all'.  Stop.

Comment: Also try 
`OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCFILES))`

Comment: You want to use patsubst like this 
`$(patsubst %suffix,%replacement,$(var))`

Comment: That got it to start but I got an error that I think has to do with the flags. If you see my original makefile, when I am making the generic .o files, you use cflags but when I am making the abc_test file, I call LDFlags. Anyway to differentiate that?

Comment: Also... my CCFlags has a hardcoded path to another file in it. If the file I am compiling is in one directory up, does that hardcoded path get screwed up? I think that is the error I am having now

Comment: expand your question with the new error. Hard to say anything without seeing the error

Comment: If you look at the original makefile, most of the lines are compiling with (CCFLAGS) and one line is compiling with (LDFLAGS) how can I differentiate them generically?

Comment: the error I am getting is:
gcc -c (filepath) %< -o %@      [NEWLINE]                                                                   
/bin/sh: -o: No such file or directory. [NEWLINE] Sorry I am not sure how to make a new line in the comment here so I put the brackets with newline as a line break

Comment: I cant say much without seeing the Makefile and you keep changing the scope of the question. Edit the question and report your new error below the old question.

Comment: I just updated my post. There is a separator bug, trying to find it now although I am very new to makefiles

Answer (score 1):

This line does not do what you think it does:

```
OBJFILES: all
```

Or at least I assume so, for although it is mostly harmless, it is also useless.  It declares that a *target* named 'OBJFILES' depends on target 'all'.  It also happens to be the first target in the file, so it is the default target, but because 'all' is its prerequiste, it will cause the 'all' target to be rebuilt by default.  This is precisely what would happen if you omitted that line altogether.  Note, too, that this has nothing to do with the *variable* `$(OBJFILES)`.

Your main problem appears to be that you are using the wrong syntax for most of your variable references.  The values of variables with multi-character names are obtained via expressions of the form `$(VAR)` or `${VAR}`, ***not*** `%(var)`.  The parentheses / braces can be omitted for single-character names.  I advise you to favor the form with parentheses over the one with curly braces, especially in commands in recipes, for the latter is easy to confuse with shell syntax.

Comment: That was one of my issues. I am able to at least get it to start running now, it just can't find files now which probably means my paths are screwed up. I just asked a question on the other post: 

"Also... my CCFlags has a hardcoded path to another file in it. If the file I am compiling is in one directory up, does that hardcoded path get screwed up? I think that is the error I am having now "

Comment: @Krixen, we can answer only the question you've actually presented, not (to us) hypotheticals about related situations.  However, if you're concerned that incorrect flags are being emitted then you can always examine `make`'s output to see exactly what commands are actually issued.  Capture the output in a file if necessary to avoid the command of interest scrolling away to oblivion.

Comment: FYI, the POSIX standard (and all implementations I'm familiar with) allows for both `$()` and `${}` as well; that's not a GNU make extension.  I personally always use `$()` unless there's some inner parentheses which would conflict.

Comment: Thanks, @MadScientist, I guess that was a longstanding misconception of mine, or maybe a memory from days when full POSIX compliance was rare.  Anyway, corrected.